# scala tail recursion decorator not letting tail recursive function to be called

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

```
object FuncUtils {
  @tailrec
  def tryAll[T](funcs: (() => Any)*): Option[Any] = {
    if (funcs.isEmpty) {
      None
    } else {
      try {
        Some(funcs.head())
      } catch {
        case _: Throwable => FuncUtils.tryAll(funcs.tail: _*)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why? It appears to me that tryAll is self contained and the iteration can occur without referencing the call stack.

Comment: why are you trying to do tail recursion over an optional?

Comment: Because the final return value is Optional. How does the return type have to do with tail recursion? @DamianLattenero

The main reason why I used recursion is because of the try catch blocks. Those are not functional constructs. I am essentially converting a procedural function into a functional one by encapsulating the concept of an exception into the Option Monad.

Comment: Recursion not really required: `funcs.toStream.flatMap(f => util.Try(f()).toOption).headOption`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is not reproducible, you may try to provide more context.

Anyways, I would also recommend you to avoid `Seq` for tail-recursive algorithms *(you should use a `List` instead)*, and `try / catch` blocks *(use the `Try` Monad instead)*.
This is a rewrite of your code using that.

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

object FuncUtils {
  def tryAll[T](funcs: (() => T)*): Option[T] = {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def loop(remaining: List[() => T]): Option[T] = remaining match {
      case Nil     => None
      case x :: xs => Try(x()) match {
        case Success(t) => Some(t)
        case Failure(_) => loop(remaining = xs)
      }
    }

    loop(remaining = funcs.toList)
  }
}
```

Again, as jwvh said, yo really do not need recursion in this case.

```
object FuncUtils {
  def tryAll[T](funcs: (() => T)*): Option[T] =
    funcs.iterator.map(f => Try(f())).collectFirst { case Success(t) => t }
}
```

Comment: Did not know about the try monad. Good answer thanks. A side question... why use lists instead of Seq for tail recursive algorithms?

Comment: In general `Seq` should be avoided, because when you have a `Seq` you really do not know what you have. Thus any operation you perform may be unsafe or have bad performance, [this](https://gist.github.com/djspiewak/2ae2570c8856037a7738) explains the problem in a more detailed way. - Now, particularly for _tail-recursive_ algorithms. One usually traverse the collection in a _head-tail_ fashion which makes sense for `Lists` because those are **O(1)** in it. But, if you have an `Array` or a `Vector` then _tail_ will be **O(N)**, because it has to copy all the data to a new collection.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the reason is because I am referring to the Singleton object that the method is contained in before calling the function.

```
 FuncUtils.tryAll(funcs.tail: _*)
```

Should just be:

```
 tryAll(funcs.tail: _*)
```

I guess scala can't figure out that its recursive when I reference the library.